# Replace hardcoded JavaScript String in WordPress Plugin

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I'd like to replace the string "Submitting" (see below) without changing the source code of the plugin.

I'm planning to replace it with a new script. What would be your code approach?

Thanks for your help!

```
$( ".aol_app_form" ).submit(function(){
        var datastring = new FormData(document.getElementById("aol_app_form"));
        $.ajax({
                url: aol_public.ajaxurl,
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: datastring,
                //async: false,
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                beforeSend: function(){
                    $('#aol_form_status').removeClass();
                    $('#aol_form_status').html('Submitting . . . . . ');
                    $('#aol_form_status').addClass('alert alert-warning');
                    $(".aol-form-button").prop('disabled', true);
                },
```

Comment: Are you building custom plugin? Where the jquey code written that you want to change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use DOMSubtreeModified for checking content change of your div #aol_form_status

```
$('#aol_form_status').bind("DOMSubtreeModified",function(){
  var content = $(this).html();
  if( content == 'Submitting . . . . . '){
    $(this).html('Your html content want to change here');
  }
});
```

Demo:

```js
$('#aol_form_status').bind("DOMSubtreeModified",function(){
  var content = $(this).html();
  if( content == 'Submitting . . . . . '){
    $(this).html('Your html content want to change here');
  }
});

$('#aol_form_status').html('Submitting . . . . . ');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="aol_form_status"></div>
```

Comment: thank you so much. perfect approach. we need a donate button or similar